# How to forward a request to another server in springboot and Zuul stack?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, netflix-zuul, angular-router

I am building a springboot and Angular 5 application. I am trying to host the springboot(On AWS) and the angular(On GitHub page) of the applications in different servers.

I am using Zuul as the reverse proxy to redirect all requests for the view to Github pages. Since it is a single page application, the requests if done sequentially works fine. For example, if  I load the home page, click and navigate to the consecutive pages, the application is rendered. If I reload the page or visit a particular URL I get a 404.

I had the same problem when I hosted the angular part on the same server with the springboot. Later fixed the issue by forwarding all view requests to the index.html.

Now **the problem is, since I host the angular files on a different server, I am not able to forward the requests to the GitHub pages. I can only redirect but not forward the requests.**

I tried forwarding using Zuul like this

```
zuul:
  routes:
    home:
      path: /**
      url: forward:https://username.github.io/repositoryname/
```

I even tried the above with the index.html at the end of the URL.

I tried forwarding in Springboot like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}" })
    public String index() {
        return "forward:https://username.github.io/repositoryname/index.html";
    }
}
```

It seems, **these forwards only work only for local URLs. I am not sure how to forward the request to an external server.** Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.